# javascript loop for taking data from XML

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps-api-3

I have this JavaScript which should loop through my XML and get my data.

Here is the javascript code I have:

```
   function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      var line =[];


  downloadUrl("exportintoxml2.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var devs = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("DEVS"),
    data = {};
    for (var n = 0; n < devs.length; n++) {
    var dev = devs[n],
     markers = dev.getElementsByTagName("marker"),
     dev_id = dev.getAttribute('DEVS');

     data[dev_id] = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("USER");
      var imei = markers[i].getAttribute("IMEI");
      var gsm1 = markers[i].getAttribute("GSM1");
      var devices = markers[i].getAttribute("DEVS");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("LAT")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("LON")));


      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + imei;
      var icon = customIcons[devices] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    data[dev_id].push = ({ 'point' : point });

    line.push(data[1]);
    }
    }



    map.setCenter(point, 16);

var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: line,
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
});

    polyline.setMap(map);           
  });   
}
```

I need a variable (or several variables) which contains all of the data for every DEV separately and I am not sure how to include it in this loop.
I need to be able to display different devices with different polylines without them being connected with each other.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a loop for `devs`.

```
var devs = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("DEVS"),
    data = {}; // for storing the data after extraction

for ( var n = 0; n < devs.length; n++ ) {
      var dev = devs[n],
          markers = dev.getElementsByTagName("marker"),
          dev_id = dev.getAttribute('devs');

      data[dev_id] = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("USER");
          var data1 = markers[i].getAttribute("DATA1");
          var data2 = markers[i].getAttribute("DATA2");
          var devs2 = markers[i].getAttribute("DEVS");
          data[dev_id].push({ 'name': name, 'data1': data1, 'data2': data2, 'devs': devs2 }); // store the data
      }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the loop. Now it loops through all of the DEVS and gets all of the data. The thing that is still not clear to me is how do you sort the data in the data[]? I am still new to javascript and I am not quite into arrays yet. I just need to have let's say.. an array with the data for each DEV, like dev1[], dev2[], etc. can that be done?

Comment: You can do that, but you should put them all in an object. See edited code above.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for the suggestion but I am still not able to achieve my goal. :) Would you please take a look at the modified code above which is the complete code I have?

Comment: I'm not sure about the code functionality overall, but change `data[dev_id].push = ({ 'point' : point });` to `data[dev_id].push({ 'point' : point });` and maybe change `line.push(data[1]);` to `line.push(data[dev_id]);`?

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
> var dev1 =
> xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("DEVS")[0];
```

*getElementsByTagName* returns a live *NodeList*. If you change it to:

```
var devs = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("DEVS");
```

you can now loop over all the DEVS elements in the document.

As for storage of all the values, you already have them in the XML document so you might consider a function that returns the values as you need them, or get them all in a loop and store them in an object (but then you likely have to loop over the objet to get them back, just like you did in the first place to put them in there).